# Live Server VScode: This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wanted to establish a live server , and quickly came across [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension.

After installing I clicked on the Go live button on right hand side corner.

A tabs automatically opens up in chrome browser  , with this error message.

I have tried doing [this](https://github.com/ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension/issues/20) , with no success.

[image]

Comment: I switched to parcel an npm package, for a live server as an immediate alternative.

Comment: We can also use the cli version that can be downloaded from npm

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This worked for me ,

I found this solution on a Github issue thread over [here](https://github.com/ritwickdey/live-server-web-extension/issues/20).

Just simply tick the checkbox stating **Use Local Ip** in the settings of vscode.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

yes, the above answer worked for me too.
Steps to follow if You are a beginner like me:

1. Click manage(it has an icon like setting).
2. Select setting from the list.
3. Select user and then expand Extension.
4. Scroll down till you find Use local Ip and check if it is unchecked.
5. Woohoo!! Test your live server, will work now.