# Live Server: This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1

Tags: liveserver

I got the message when I use live server at VS code.
This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1

I checked use local up option. but it still doesn't working.

I tried changing live server : host ip address to my ip address. But it still doesn't working.

what can I do?

*use local ip as host option picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/COq2I.png

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example so we can help?

Comment: The problem I'm having is very much the same as this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169067/live-server-vscode-this-page-isn-t-working-127-0-0-1-didn-t-send-any-data-err 
But I tried the answer of that question. But it doesn't working.

Comment: To explain in detail. when I use attribute "method=post" I got the error "This page isn't working". When I use "method=get", it works well.

Answer (score 0):

#### In your given image, you have `checked` the option that hosts the `liveserver` on your IP, so you should have a look at `yourip:port`.

##### For example, if you is `10.43.156.141`, and post is `5500` then

### the server will be on `http://10.43.156.141:5500`

---

#### EDIT

To get your IP

- If you are using `Windows`, use:

```sh
C:\User>ipconfig
```

- If you have `Linux`, use:

```sh
$ ifconfig
```

Or just visit [`https://api.ipify.org/`](https://api.ipify.org/) to get your IP.

> Note: When you visit https://api.ipify.org/ disable your VPN or Brave Shield or any Privacy Booster if you have

#### Edit:

The port is shown here
[image]

#### Edit the port in the live server

If you dont know the `port`, just add the below code in vscode's `settings.json`

```
"liveServer.settings.port": 5500
```

##### Change the `5500` to the port you want. Mostly `5500` is used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
How can i find the post number?

Comment: Thanks again. but i already used ipconfig. The only thing i got is 
ipv4 address. I can't find the post number.

Comment: mostly, the live server in the vs code uses the port `5500` try using that

Comment: i really appreciate it.
It's sad but it doesn't work.
The following is what i wrote on settings.json.

"liveServer.settings.useLocalIp": true,
"liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": false, <- it made automatically
"liveServer.settings.host": "my ip address",
"liveServer.settings.port": 5500,
"liveServer.settings.proxy": {
     "proxyUri": "my ip address:5500"
}'

Answer (score 0):

Try using IPv4 Address.
Fo example if your IPv4 Address is 172.31.96.1 and your file name is index.html, Then change the URL in the browser from http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html to http://172.31.96.1:5500/index.html

Comment: Change it in the Live Server › Settings: Host in VS Code